# Using identity with custom user object

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to get this for a week now. I have read  several articles on how to do it. Nevertheless I think it should not be as complicated as everybody states, running migrations/overriding and making your own implementation of userStore(thats why I'm trying to use identity), etc. Following this documentation i was able to create an identity user ["ASP NET identity From empty project"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)

[image]

The table AspNetUsers is being populated ok, but what i would like to do is to add some more columns to this table. Here is what i  have tried but keeps  throwing me error.

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        var db = new IdentityDbContext(value);
        var userStore = new UserStore<UsuarioTest>(db);
        var manager = new UserManager<UsuarioTest>(userStore);


        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = usuario.Nombre };
        var us = new UsuarioTest
        {
            Nombre = usuario.Nombre,
            Email = usuario.Email,
            UserName = usuario.Nombre,
            TelefonoCelular = usuario.TelefonoCelular,
            Password = usuario.Password
        };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(us, usuario.Password);
```

As you can see I replaced IdentityUser by UsuarioTest but this does not work properly. If I leave the IdentityUser and complete this object evrything works fine.

Finally here is my implementation for usuarioTest

```
public class UsuarioTest : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Nombre { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string TelefonoCelular { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; }
    //public string UserName { get; set; }

    public UsuarioTest()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

I hope this description is good enough for you guys guide me to a solution.

PS:I  have already tried searching applicationUser and modify this class but this is from an old version of identity. I am currently using Identity core 4.0

Comment: Your ApplicationDbContext class must inherit IdentityDbContext<UsuarioTest> instead of IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>

Comment: Ok. So after struggling with some Identity implementation for NHibernate I realized that those libraries have several bugs. I found myself fixing one error after another. I ended up using Facebook API Graph (which is really easy to use) and managing all new users by myself (which is a pain). As usually stated.. no pain no gain. Thanks for the help Efe.

Comment: :) Finally, it is better to have control on your own code, rather than being under control of one's code. You did the right thing.